# civibanking documentation

Tags: civibanking

When creating a contribution or matching a contribution against a bank statement the matching scripts contain a bunch of attributes for which I cannot find an explanation anywhere. Any suggestions? They include:
received_date_minimum, date_penalty, amount_relative_minimum, amount_penalty, soft_cap_probability

Comment: For reference, documentation is at https://docs.civicrm.org/banking/en/latest/user-guide/ but from a quick skim I don't think it includes the detail requested.

Comment: Thanks Aidan, but I have already tried that resource and as you say it is missing the detail that I am seeking